# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) "Desktop" disk space requirements?

Tags: 20.04, .desktop

I plan to install the desktop version of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) on my machine in the near future.

I have tons of disk space and am first planning on partitioning the disk for my own custom partitioning strategy.  I'm wondering what the minimum size partition I can get away with that would house this version of Ubuntu, 10GB of space, 15GB os space, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current Ubuntu Desktop requirements are listed at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

As of late 2020:

> Recommended system requirements:
>
> - 2 GHz dual core processor or better
> - 4 GB system memory
> - 25 GB of free hard drive space
> - Internet access is helpful
> - Either a DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

Answer (score 1):

That largely depends on what you use it for and how you want to use it.

If you have an SSD use that for these two:

- 20 Gb for / is enough for a desktop user. That is excluding `/home/` if you plan to use it.
- `/home/` can be as large as you want. If you do not plan to use `/home`/ you can forget about it and include it in the 20 Gb for /

These 2 benefit from the speed of an SSD.

Use a HDD for this

- Personal data you can store on a second disk. You can use a personal mount point for this. Point any download to this partition.

If you plan to develop websites, use a database server change the location of each of these to point to the personal partition.

The idea is to keep the (ssd in this case) the system dependent software and settings for software on 1 disk and anything personal on another.

Comment: I see on the Ubuntu server documentation a page like this: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation  I am hoping to get a link to the equivalent for the Ubuntu Desktop equivalent but am ont seeing it.  This server page shows all the "System Requirements".

Comment: @wg11492 The Desktop requirements are clearly listed at https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Do not ignore this answer -- it is very good.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you, was exactly what I was looking for.  It doesn't look like I can accept this as an answer though since it's a nested reply.